# How to return the key of an array of objects using its name

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, key, key-value

NOTE: I know what I'm attempting to do logically doesn't make sense in terms of why I want to achieve this, however I just want to know if it's possible and if so what I might be writing wrong?

I'm working with an array of objects like so:

```
this.animalsAndFruits = [
  {
    "category": "Apple",
    "num1": 1287,
    "num2": 12956
  },
  {
    "category": "Panda",
    "num1": 2574,
    "num2": 25826
  },
  ....
]
```

This may seem tedious and rather ridiculous however using the array I want to return the word 'category', not the value just the key 'category'.

I've tried

```
this.objectFromArray[0].category
```

However it only returns the value of the 0th indexed item (even though the 0th indexed item key will always have key 'category')

Is there another way I can accomplish this?

P.S. The reason why I want to get 'category' is because I need to set a variable = 'category', however I don't want to hardcode it directly like this

```
var someVar  = 'category'
```

If it helps, the value in the key:value pair where the key = category is always a string (whereas all of the other values under different keys are numbers.

Maybe logic like so might work =>

```
if(value = string) then return key  ?
```

Comment: Not sure why you want `this.objectFromArray[0].category` to return `category` since you have `category` in that line ... anyway using `Object.keys(this.objectFromArray[0])` may be a step towards what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the non-`category` properties have a consistent format (`num#`, right? at least going by [the prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491073/convert-multidimensional-array-to-objects-using-dynamically-generated-and-predef/64491129#64491129)), if you want to find the key which does *not* start with `num`, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys, then `.find` the key matching the condition:

```js
const animalsAndFruits = [
  {
    "category": "Apple",
    "num1": 1287,
    "num2": 12956
  },
  {
    "category": "Panda",
    "num1": 2574,
    "num2": 25826
  },
];

const propertyName = Object.keys(animalsAndFruits[0]).find(
  key => !key.startsWith('num')
);
console.log(propertyName);
```

If you happen to be able to depend on the non-`num` key always being the first one defined in the objects, you could also use `Object.keys(animalsAndFruits[0])[0]`.